# Plotly Dash: How to store input-data in multipage app?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I hope that someone can help me on the problem i'm facing at the moment. I'm building a 3-pages dash app, and I'm struggling to use the dcc.store component.

On the first page there is an input-field where users can input their name. I would like to store the name so that I can use it on page 2. But for some reason I don't get it working the way I want it to. Here's the code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output,State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate


#############################################
########### variables & settings ############
#############################################

## app variabelen
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])  
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
len_data = 3500

#############################################
########### setup app-components ############
#############################################

## header met paginaselecties
navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
        children=[
                dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Login",href="/login"),id='nav_login'),
                dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Recode",href="/recode"),id='nav_recode'),
        ],
        brand="recode",
        brand_href="/",
        color="primary",               
)

#############################################
############### layout pages ################
#############################################

## layout pagina 1   
page_1 = html.Div([navbar, 
        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                dbc.FormGroup([dbc.Label("Name"),
                               dbc.Input(id="name",
                                         type="text",
                                         placeholder="...")], 
                                         className="m-3"),
                               html.Div(id='output_name')
                    ],style={'width':'40%'}),
                    ]),
                ])


## layout pagina 2
page_2 = html.Div([navbar,
                   html.Div(id='name_output')
                ])

#############################################
################ layout app #################
#############################################

app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Store(id='session',
                  data=[{'name':'Leeg'}]),
        dcc.Location(id='url',refresh=False),
        html.Div(id='page-content')
    ])
                        
#############################################
############# callbacks routing #############
#############################################               
@app.callback(Output('page-content','children'),
              [Input('url','pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/login':
        return page_1
    elif pathname == '/recode':
        return page_2

@app.callback(Output('nav_login','active'),
              [Input('url','pathname')])
def set_page_1_active(pathname):
    return pathname == '/login'

@app.callback(Output('nav_recode','active'),
              [Input('url','pathname')])
def set_page_2_active(pathname):
    return pathname == '/recode'


#############################################
################# callbacks  ################
#############################################  

@app.callback(
        Output('session','data'),
        [Input('name','value')])
def return_name(value):
    if value is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    data = [{'name':value}]
    return data

@app.callback(
        Output('name_output','data'),
        [Input('session','data')])
def print_name(name):
    return name

@app.callback(
        Output('slider_output','children'),
        [Input('slider_select','value')])
def update_slider(value):
    return "You've selected {} from total ({})".format(value,len_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True,port=8050)
```

Hopefully someone can help me. I can allways use the hidden-Div scenario, but I really want to use the dcc.store so that I can use it in the future as well...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dcc.Store()` component is working fine, the source of the problem is the `print_name()` callback:

- In the callback you are referencing the `'data'` property of the `html.Div()` with `id='name_output'` instead of the `'children'` property which is where the contents of the `html.Div()` are actually stored; see the Dash documentation for more details: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/div.
- In order to print the input text on the screen you would need to extract it from the data saved in the `dcc.Store()` component as follows `name = data[0]['name']` given that  `data = [{'name': value}]`.

If you update the `print_name()` callback in line with the code below your app should work.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('name_output', 'children'),
    [Input('session', 'data')])
def print_name(data):
    name = data[0]['name']
    return name
```